# Homework / test. Thevenin equivalent

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I decided to create this circuit and solve it with mesh analysis. Then, I thought I could find the Thevenin Equivalent, but I have no idea where to start! I can't get to understand how to get the thevenin voltage when I have the open circuit right in the middle. If you could help me out with the way I should do it, that would be great. Thanks! (I'm trying to solve it myself, so I'm looking more for an explanation than an answer itself)

[image]

Comment: [1]: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/thevenin.htmlhttp://
  [2]: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenins-theorem/

Comment: Prakash Darji, "Link only answers" are discouraged. That being said, it's sorta warranted, and I do highly recommend the second link.

As for your specific hangup, Mylane, the open in the center is good, even necessary for getting the Thevenin voltage. It's all the other jazz that's not doing you any favors.

You should try the process on some simpler circuits first if you don't get what to do. This way may feel too trivial, but you'll come to understand the merits of the process just from going through the motions.

Again, that second link is a really good reference.

Comment: There's a schematic editor in the editor toolbar, it will allow you to make a much more readable, less fuzzy circuit. Also, you should post your attempt at solving the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mylane, are you trying to solve for Vin by only doing Thevenin or will you like to solve for Vin in multiple ways?

Here is one way without doing Thevenin Equivalent:

The voltage across the 6 ohm and 4 ohm resistors together is the same voltage as 3Vx. Vx is the same voltage across 4 ohms resistor.

**Going anticlockwise in the last loop with Ohm's Law (V = I*R):**

-3Vx + 6ip + Vx = 0

6ip = 3Vx - Vx

ip = 2Vx/6

= Vx/3

**Since the 6 ohm and 4 ohm resistors are in series, they have the same current flowing through them**

Thus Vx = 4 x ip **(Ohm's Law)**

Let's call the current **going DOWN (not UP)** thru 2 ohm and 12 ohm resistors since they are in series **i2**

So when adding the current at the 12 ohm and 1 Amp Current Source node, **(assuming all positive currents are leaving that node)**

-1/2ip - i2 + 1A = 0

i2 = 1 - 1/2ip

Thus the voltage across the 2 ohm resistor, let's call that V2

**Using Ohm's Law V2 = 2 * i2**

Looking at the middle upper loop,

**Going clockwise with Ohm's Law (V = I*R):**

-Vin - V2 - 8v + 6ip = 0

Vin = 6ip - V2 - 8v

Vin = 6ip - (-3ip) - 8v

Vin = 9ip - 8v

For some reason everything seems to cancel each other out. Did you make up this circuit yourself or was it given to you?

Comment: I did it myself. Does it really cancel out? :0 And I'm just practicing thevenin equivalent. That's why I'm asking where should I start.

Comment: So this is not the original circuit? Did you take out the load at Vin? At nodes a-b?

Comment: Yes, an 8 Ohm resistor used to be there. I just thought that was the best position to take out the load and calculate the thevenin equivalent.

Comment: @Mylane, Okay now I understand. You created the circuit with an 8 ohm resistor and try to get the thevenin equivalent looking at it from the 8 ohm resistor load. There is nothing wrong with that. Yes it cancels out. Can you get another problem from a book/online with answers, so that we can check if we get it right? Also doing thevenin equivalent with dependent sources is not the easiest thing to do, but nontheless we'll get it done. Do u know how to get the Thevenin resistance?

Comment: Well, kinda. I'm lost with this circuit. I know how to get it in a circuit where the a-b part is on a side of the circuit. When it is right in the middle, I get lost. I do it with the tension source and getting the current with mesh analysis using superposition. And I can't get to find a circuit that looks similar to this one in a book with answers, most of them look alike.

Comment: @Mylane, let's take it step by step. Where are you lost in this circuit? Let's start from there, then after we are done with this circuit (although it is faulty, let's pretend nothing is wrong with it), we will try other problems.

Comment: I still don't get how you find the Vth in this one, with the dependet sources.

Comment: @Mylane, when you say Vth (Thevenin Voltage), Im assuming you are talking about Vin. That's basically what I did at the top. I used Ohm's Law to get it. Can you please look at what I did at the top, and ask me where you are lost at?

Comment: The last part, when you find Vin. I can't get to understand where you got that equation from.

Comment: @Mylane, I did a KVL (Kirchoff's Voltage Law) in the middle upper loop.

Comment: Oh, okay! I see it. By the way, when I replace the vx in the ip equation, it goes ip=ip. Why does that happen? That's the "it cancels out" thing?

Comment: @Mylane, yes that is what I was talking about.

Comment: So, there's no way to solve this circuit? Like, the vth wouldn't be -8v? Or the thevenin eq. be just a thevenin resistance?

Comment: There might be another way 2 solve the circuit, Im not sure, since we don't have a verified answer. That's y I suggested we get an online problem or one from a book with a verified answer. You can get the thevenin resistance, by killing all INDEPEDENT POWER SOURCES adding a one amp test current at nodes a-b, then getting the voltage across that one amp test current power source and using ohm's law to get thevenin resistance or you could add an one volt test voltage at nodes a-b, then get the current thru the one volt test voltage power source and using ohm's law to get the thevenin resistance.

Comment: So, as far as this goes, I cannot express this circuit as a thevenin equivalent?

Comment: You can, but in symbols (not with a numerical value, as far as I know). You just have to get the Thevenin Resistance (which might end up being in symbols as well).

Comment: I think I've noticed the mistake. Is the current ip going down thru the 6 ohms resistor or is it going thru the 8v source?

Comment: Through the 6 ohm res

Comment: @Mylane, do u have another problem we should try, or should I get us one?

Comment: No, I can't find another, at least, not similar to this one. If you could find one, that would be great. Thanks! Bye the way, how do I find the thevenin resistance with this one? Should I do superposition? Or I just kill all sources at the same time?

Comment: @Mylane,  You can get the thevenin resistance, by killing all INDEPEDENT POWER SOURCES at the same time, adding a one amp test current at nodes a-b, then getting the voltage across that one amp test current source and using ohm's law to get thevenin resistance or you could add an one volt test voltage at nodes a-b, then get the current thru the one volt test voltage source and using ohm's law to get the thevenin resistance

Comment: Hey, you've been really kind. Thanks for your help, thanks a lot! If you can find an exercise with answers similar to this one, I'd be glad to see it, I'm still looking for one. Other than that, thanks :D

Comment: @Mylane, sorry for the late response, have you been able to come up with another one? I have come up with many, just in case you need some.

Comment: Oh yes, I haven´t :c That'd be so helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @Mylane, Im coming, let me get it for you then.